# Is there no current between these terminals?

Tags: transistors, current

This is related to charge carries movements out of transistor terminals. Assuming a transistor in common emitter connection is biased properly where resistors are omitted for simplicity. Before asking the question here is what I know:

From V3's negative terminal the electrons will enter to the emitter terminal following the path A->B->C.

Most of these electrons will be drifted to the collector and from there they will follow X->Y->Z. The rest of the electrons will recombine with the holes in the base and will cause electron flow from the base to D.

My questions is:

Is there literally no charge movements(current) between B and K?

[image]

Comment: If there's base current it has to flow through the K-B segment of the wire.  If there's a collector current (other than leakage) then there's a base current.  See Kirchhoff's current law.

Comment: Yes that is why I was confused. I used to believe that artificial current has to flow in loops. But the "electrons" forming the base terminal current seems are not passing through K and B.

Comment: What’s an artificial current? You should get used to conventional current, which is in the opposite direction to electron current.

Comment: @Chu Artifical current is the current caused by an alternator or a voltaic battery. The current caused by static electric does not flow in loops afaik. Like in a lightning strike.

Comment: I was trying to point the current flows in loops dogma.

Comment: I’ve not heard the term ‘artificial current’.

Comment: There is no possibility of static build-up in this circuit. You can consider static as a charge on a capacitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. There are two current loops, I<sub>b</sub> and I<sub>c</sub>. Conventional current is indicated by the direction of the arrows.*

There can't be any loss in current around the base loop or around the collector loop.

At one section of the circuit - between C and B - the current flowing is I<sub>b</sub> + I<sub>c</sub>.

From the comments:

> The current caused by static electric does not flow in loops afaik. Like in a lightning strike.

It's still a loop. It's the same as discharging a charged capacitor. Once charge starts to flow it's static no longer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFRCKj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Lightning discharge equivalent circuit.*

Comment: Are the electrons looping in Cathode-ray tubes?

Comment: But can you also elaborate on the Iceo leakage current for the circuit in question? It originates at CB junction due to temperature. So the Iceo does not originate from the battery. Does it loop between C and B junctions? Thanks

Comment: @cm64 Yes, they are.

Comment: "*Are the electrons looping in Cathode-ray tubes?*" See the answers to [Where do the electrons go in a CRT?](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/where-do-the-electrons-go-in-a-crt.612606/). They have to get back to the supply somehow.

Comment: Regarding \$ {I_{CBO}} \$ see if [ICEO, ICBO physical interpretation in BJT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/124668/iceo-icbo-physical-interpretation-in-bjt) answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

The current you have between Base in D is also flowing between K and B. The current there has the value of I/ß, with I the current from A to B and ß the amplification of the transitor.

Comment: To me the "electrons" forming the base terminal current are attracted by the positive side of V1 and ends their journey at D. How come they pass through K and B again I dont get it.

Comment: A current always has to form a closed loop. If there is charge going into the positiv terminal, then there always has to be charging flowing out of the negativ terminal.

Comment: Because if there is current going in or out of V1 at D then the same current must go out or into V1 at K.

Comment: Yes that is what I memorized but in this case it is not clear.

Comment: @Transistor What moves are the electrons from the base those electrons are not coming from V1's negative terminal. (?)

Comment: Your last comment is missing some punctuation so it is difficult to know what you are asking. Thinking in terms of electrons leads to great confusion. You are far better to think in terms of conventional current. As has been explained, current flows in closed loops. If electrons flow into the top of V1 then (different) electrons flow out the bottom of V1.

Comment: Okay so the electrons coming from A and K add up and forms the emitter current. Then very small part of these electrons are recombined in the base with holes. Now the base gives out some electrons to V1's positive terminal which is equal to the current between K and B.  (?)

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is, but they are at the same charge potential so the net is 0. (disregarding any miniscule wire resistance)

Comment: What carriers are moving between K and B?

Comment: Electrons of course.

Comment: The electrons flows from the base to V1's positive terminal and they end their journey there. Can you elaborate? I cannot reason any other electron movement.

Comment: This answer is not correct - or at least not worded correctly. The not-insignificant base current flows from V1 through D -> C -> B -> K and back to V1. If you want to think in terms of electron flow then it runs the opposite direction.

Comment: @cm64, they don't end their journey there. They participate in chemical reactions in the battery. From those reactions, electrons are produced on the other battery terminal, which flow through the wires KB and BC to the BJT emitter terminal. (Remembering also that no individual electron makes this whole journey)

Comment: @ThePhoton This is very clear now. But one last part of the puzzle left. Do you know where the loop starts for the leakage current Iceo and where it ends in this case? What I think is that Iceo in the form of electrons flows from the collector base junction back to the collector base junction so the loop for Iceo is X-Y-Z-A-B-C is that correct?(In between there are recombinations ect.)

Comment: @cm64: a loop does not have a "start" and "end", because it is a continuous loop, like a circle.

Comment: I should have called it path. But this Iceo is not created at any battery it is created by minority charge carriers of CB junction and I wonder how we can think of this path. Because if the config becomes voltage divider bias would all the Iceo still flow the same way? I cannot find any detailed info about these.