# What will happen if we give voltage to a transistor (BJT) across emitter and collector without connecting the base?

Tags: transistors, bjt

What will happen if we give voltage to a transistor (BJT) across emitter and collector without connecting the base? Will it conduct current?

And what will happen to the barrier potential which is across emitter-base and base-collector?

Comment: It might help, in this case, consider the transistor as two back to back diodes (even if you won't get transistor action from two diodes). One diode will be reverse biased, letting through only a current of the order of its reverse saturation current, while the other will be weakly forward biased with that tiny current flowing through and a correspondingly small voltage developed across it. KCL requires both currents to be equal in magnitude.

Answer (score 7):

There will be some small current from collector to emitter due to leakage.

First of all, linear models of a BJT (like hybrid pi model) often include a resistance in parallel with the collector to emitter path.

Second there is some small leakage from collector to base.  That leakage will then be amplified by the base (as any other base current would be) resulting in additional collector to emitter current.

Comment: "That leakage will then be amplified by the base".....amplified by the base? What does this mean? What is "the base"? Please, can you further explain and give some reference to this statement?

Comment: @LvW As you are almost certainly aware, a BJT has three connection points that are typically labeled Collector, Base, and Emitter.  The amount of amplification (current wise) is the ratio of the collector and base currents (usually called B or Hfe).  Ic = B * Ib should still be valid even if the base current is due to internal leakage from the collector to base junction.  See this stackexchange post https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/124668/iceo-icbo-physical-interpretation-in-bjt

Comment: So you think that in the case under discussion the leakage current is amplified by the factor B ? Are you aware that the BJT is a device which is controlled by the voltage Vbe? More than that, in the expression Ib=Ic/B the factor B relates the base current Ib (between B and E) with the current Ic. And the equation tells us only that Ib is a certain fraction of Ic. Nothing else!

Comment: @LvW But won't any leakage current into the base automatically generate base-emitter voltage. How can you have one without the other?  As long as the Base-Emitter junction is forward biased, the equation Vbe = n * Vt * ln(Ie/Is + 1) should hold for any applied current, and Ie = Is*(e^(Vbe/vt/n)-1) should hold for any applied base-emitter voltage. Note that Ie = emitter current, Is = base-emitter reverse saturation current, n = diode ideality factor, Vbe =base emitter voltage, Vt = thermal voltage.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot agree. You are speaking about an "applied base-emitter voltage". But there is no (externally) applied Vbe. More than that, as a simplification we assume that a current could "generate" a voltage . But physically this is wrong. Of course, there will be a certain (small) voltage across the B-E junction - but not as a result of the leakage current. In contrast - the applied voltage Vce drives a leakage current through both pn junctions - and we have a voltage division between the C-B and the B-E path. However, without the classical amplifying effect.

Comment: With other words: Of course, the width of the depletion zone within the B-E junction depends on the applied Voltage Vce (Early effect)) - and with it the amount of leakage current. But this is not the result of any amplifying effect within the transistor. In particular, the known exponential equation Ic=f(Vbe/VT) does not apply in this case.

Comment: @LvW Well I pulled my box of 1000 x 2N222A transistors off the shelf and put 20V between collector and emitter, and measured base to emitter with a two different DMMs.  Surprisingly I saw -0.6V (rather than +0.6V like one would expect).  To eliminate the possibility of some bias current from the meter affecting the measurement I swapped the meter lead polarity (but measured the same).  Whatever was creating the -0.6V had very little output power because it was quite easily made to be 0V by putting a 1.6M resistor between B and E.  In any case it wasn't making a positive voltage like I expected

Comment: @user4574 One does not simply walk into Mord--- I mean, one does not simply measure a voltage across those terminals. I believe you are measuring the effects of capacitive coupling with nearby mains lines. If your voltmeter has a bar graph, you should see it shimmering. (With my DMM I read -1.4V in DC mode)

Comment: Ok, I went out in the middle of the garden, far away from the underground cables and, with an 8v battery at nearly 0 degree Celsius I can read about +400 mV stable with an UT139C on the 600mV scale. EDIT simulated in LTSpice at 0°C I get 380mV which is a better agreement that I thought, considering mine is not high tech lab instrumentation. My UT61E goes in overload on its 200mV range, but reads a handful of mV on the Volt autorange, confirming that in a quiet place the input resistance alters the measurement. BRRRRRrrrr... It's cold out there.

Answer (score 3):

In datasheets this is defined at limits as $$ _{Collector-Emitter ~Breakdown  ~Voltage ~~~ V_{(BR)CEO} = 40~ @ ~ Ic=1mA,Ib=0}$$ for a typical general purpose transistor like the MMBT3904. This is leakage resistance due to the “Early Effect”.